# Diode Stack SPICE Modeling

Tags: power, diodes, spice, modeling

When I model a 7 diode stack in SPICE (LTSPICE or core Smartspice within Silvaco TCAD) the standard level 1 'Berkeley' model works, but the Philips model fails. The Philips diode model (see Smartspice spice model manual) provides a detailed forward and reverse DC static modeling of a diode.  The standard model is pretty much the ideal diode equation.

I ultimately am moving toward the cmc_diode model, which is pretty much just a combination of the Philips and HiSim (has recovery time modeling) with a few modifications. But will any detailed modeling of the forward and reverse static characteristics ultimately fail in a series stack of diodes?  Will it not fail in parallel though?

I want to have detailed modeling of the forward and reverse IV and reverse recovery of actual diodes I have being manufactured. Also modeling this high voltage, high current diode stack within other power circuits and want accurate model when compared to experiment.

There is not a lot on the modeling of diode stacks.  The single diode model used for a stacked diode does not parameterically fit the experimental curves as well.  The parameter fitting is also different for a diode stack.  Maybe there are some experts on diode modeling in SPICE and specifically diode stacks that know how to model accurately the standard diode experimental tests and in other power circuit applications?

So how to model a diode stack in SPICE accurately when compared to various electrical experiments is my question.

---

I might add that I program in C the Philips model into the user-defined models available in the Silvaco TCAD core-Smartspice.  I haven't added any special convergence methods to this, that may exist in the Smartspice Philips and cmc_diode models.  I've run TCAD models of diode stacks fine and spice standard diode models fine.  I'll soon test the philips and hisim models in smartspice (when my license comes back) for diode stack convergence issues.

Also the convergence issues occur internally in the models as infinity and not a number results.  The Isrh (recombination current), Itat (trap-assisted tunneling), and Ibbt (band to band tunneling) are accounted for in the diode current model as well as an avalanche mutliplication effect. These additional terms cause the convergence issues as inf or nan. I solved one issue, but cannot solve the others.  This failure to converge does not happen with a single diode using the Philips model.

Comment: Jay Eifler - Welcome to the site :-) Stack Exchange is different from typical internet forums. Please see the [tour] and [help] for more details. Any improvements to a question (e.g. more details & clarifications) should be added into the question as an *edit* (see the edit link below the question), not added as comments. Although you can add [comments](/help/privileges/comment), you would usually only do so to reply to other people's comments seeking clarification etc. (see that previous link). I will move those comments into the question. Thanks.

Comment: I think that this question will get more traction at the Physics Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Jay Can you provide a schematic of the diode stack (there is a tool avalible if you edit to draw schematics)?  Is this a single component\IC or several components?

Comment: @Syed Typically spice questions are better handled here, physics SE does not cover spice

Comment: Jay, I can't tell from reading (I'm not familiar with some of what you are working with) if you are in a situation where you need to deal with imperfections and their statistics as well as things like the formation of surface channels, surface carrier recombination effects, or current-crowding, for example. For detailed modeling, years ago, I needed to use lots of 3D integrals and information about dopants that I had to reverse-engineer through experiment since the manufacturer wasn't forthcoming. In your case, you may know these things.

Comment: @VoltageSpike: Thanks for the clarification. I think that questions about usage of SPICE models fit here. The semiconductor modeling aspect will get more responses over the Physics SE  The question as posed is vague. Let the OP clarify it some more.

Comment: So this is a single component device. And yes there would be imperfections or real device characteristics that need capturing with the more detailed forward and reverse iv modeling in the spice model by including terms in the current equation for recombination, trap-assisted tunneling, band to band tunneling, non-ideal forward current, etc.

Comment: My question is whether of the various diode spice models if all that have more detailed modeling fail to converge when used for a diode stack by merely putting diodes in series in the simulation.  I think parallel must work fine in convergence but I could be wrong.  The standard diode model works fine but more advanced models I've programmed in from the equations.  But maybe there are special convergence techniques in the professional advanced models.  Like the HiSIM, Philips and cmc_diode models as examples of advanced models.

Comment: It's something to consider that diode models that go beyond the standard model fail to converge for the diodes in series.  This is a failure to generate the static DC curves in forward and reverse bias when a more detailed model capturing the shape of the curves in detail is used.  This static aspect of the model serves as the basis, along with capacitance modeling (done in ac usually), for large signal transient simulation (80% of all spice simulation is for transient results).

Comment: And the standard model doesn't include recovery time modeling or for that matter avalanche effects that would appear in the reverse iv. And the standard model forces the use of transit time of the forward capacitance to be reassigned to recovery time somewhat inadequately.

Comment: A comment by someone whose an expert in advanced diode models, their convergence, and their use in series especially in high power application circuits would be helpful.